# Java Swing's TableModel getValueAt responsibility

Tags: java, swing, tablemodel

What responsibilities fall with Java Swing's [TableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html)...

Who should present the formatted display to the user?
Is there any official guidance?

## JavaDocs

The help for `getValueAt` states:

> Returns the value for the cell at columnIndex and rowIndex.

There is no mention of formatting here.  It returns "the value" for the cell.  An `Object`.

I have seen different implementations - even in products I have worked on.  I feel there isn't much consistency.

## Examples

**TableModel**

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.###");

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
    ...
    decimalFormat.format(myObjectModel.GetFoo(row).getSomeDoubleProperty());
}
```

**DefaultTableCellRenderer**

```
public final class PositionDoubleCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    private final String formatPattern = "%,.03f";

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
            final JTable table, Object value, final boolean isSelected, final boolean hasFocus, final int row, final int column
    ) {
        String formattedValue = "";

        if (value instanceof Double) {
            double numeric = (Double) value;

            if (ConstantsModel.isConstant(numeric)) {
                formattedValue = "";
            } else {
                formattedValue = String.format(formatPattern, numeric);
            }
        }

        return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, formattedValue, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    }
}
```

There are pro's and con's depending on which mechanism you use.  I don't know of any other ways to format off the top of my head, but I have had this thought on my mind for a while now.

Comment: Well, it depends. Is your model to actually expose the data as strings? If so formatting the doubles in `getValueAt()` would be ok. If the model is meant to expose the actual data types (I'd prefer that) then the renderer might be the better approach. My guess is that returning the formatted string from the model felt easier for the devs since they didn't have to come up with a renderer.

Comment: As far as "official guidance" goes (at least to my knowledge): As you correctly pointed out "Returns _the value_ for the cell at columnIndex and rowIndex." already states that it should be the value and not the formatted representation.

Comment: Yeah, I get that feeling too.  But in order to have consistent formatting of data in different tables for doubles, you then have to open up each table model and change for getValueAt.  I just get a feeling of SRP and OCP violations at play with formatting in the getValueAt.

Comment: Well, I'd say that when formatting needs to be consistent the same renderer should be used for different tables. And if the formatting needs to be applied to a specific column only then that column's type should probably be something specific as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Who should present the formatted display to the user?

The view. The `JTable` uses `renderers` to format/display the data.

> in order to have consistent formatting of data in different tables for doubles, you then have to open up each table model and change for getValueAt

The data should not change. Therefore the getValueAt(...) method should not change.

A renderer can be shared by multiple tables.

You can even change the way the data is presented to the table by overriding the `getColumnClass(...)` method of a `JTable`.

The table has some default renderers for  Boolean.class, Number.class, Icon.class etc.

So, for example if you have an Integer value stored in the model and if you override the `getColumnClass(...)` method of the table to return:

1. `Integer.class` - the data will be formatted as a number and displayed right aligned
2. `Object.cloass` - the data will be treated like a String and displayed left justified.

Or you can even assign a custom renderer to a specific column in the `TableColumnModel`. So if you wanted the Integer formatted as a "percentage" you can use a renderer for that.

So, bottom line is the same data can be displayed in an unlimited number of ways when the proper renderer is used.

Check out [Table Format Renderers](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/table-format-renderers/) for an easy way to create reusable formatting renderers.